# Zebra Striped vs Line Separator vs Plain for a list of items?

Tags: usability, lists, readability

I am designing a news site the is will list a lot of news articles in a compact space. I have tried the following 3 ways to separate the articles, and I'm wondering which is the best from a UX perspective?

Zebra: 
[image: zebra]

Lines:
[image: Lines]

Plain:
[image: Plain]

Comment: I don't think that there is a 'best' answer here, but the decision could be based on a number of different considerations such as the general look & feel of the website, the amount of space available, the suitability of applying the same styling similar content on other pages, etc.

Comment: If you were to give the primary criteria that you're using to determine which is "best", the question may be answerable.  However, right now it's primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Of the options you show I would go with the 'plain'. The distinctive image in each row is likely enough to visually separate rows. The striping and lines only add noise.

(Always good to test though …)

Answer (score 0):

The stripes are more for data tables when you have to follow top to bottom.  Also, if not lines there needs to be clear separation between each result.

Comment: Yes, zebra striping helps you read across long rows in a data table. That's not necessary here.